# Passing column name as parameter in Oracle PL_SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to pass two input parameters, column name and table name . Then the function should output a string value as defined below :

```
create or replace function get_id5(in_col_name IN VARCHAR2,in_tbl_name IN VARCHAR2)
  return VARCHAR2
is
  /*in_col_nm varchar(32) := in_col_name;
  /*in_tbl_nm varchar(64) := in_tbl_name; */
  integer_part  NUMBER ;
  integer_part_str VARCHAR2(32) ;
  string_part VARCHAR2(32) ;
  full_id VARCHAR2(32) ;
  out_id VARCHAR(32) ;

BEGIN
/*select MAX(in_col_nm) INTO full_id FROM  in_tbl_nm ;  */
execute immediate 'select MAX('||in_col_name||') FROM' || in_tbl_name ||'INTO' || full_id;
/*select regexp_replace(full_id , '[^0-9]', '') INTO integer_part_str  , regexp_replace(full_id , '[^a-z and ^A-Z]', '') INTO string_part from dual ; */
integer_part_str := regexp_replace(full_id , '[^0-9]', '') ;
string_part := regexp_replace(full_id , '[^a-z and ^A-Z]', '') ;
integer_part := TO_NUMBER(integer_part_str);
integer_part  := integer_part  + 1 ;
integer_part_str  := TO_CHAR(integer_part) ;
out_id  :=  string_part + integer_part_str   ;
return out_id;
END;
```

I have a table named BRANDS in Database and the max value for column BRAND_ID is 'Brand05'. The expected output is 'Brand06'.

However when i run:
`select get_id5('BRAND_ID' , 'BRANDS') from dual;`

or

```
DECLARE
a VARCHAR(32) ;
BEGIN
a := get_id5('BRAND_ID' , 'BRANDS');
END;
```

I am getting the below error:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces between the `FROM` and the table_name and the `INTO` should be outside of the SQL text:

```sql
execute immediate 'select MAX('||in_col_name||') FROM ' || in_tbl_name INTO full_id;
```

You could also use `DBMS_ASSERT`:

```sql
execute immediate 'select MAX('||DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(in_col_name)||') FROM ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(in_tbl_name) INTO full_id;
```

Then you need to use `||` as the string concatenation operator (rather than `+`).

Your function could be:

```sql
create or replace function get_id5(
  in_col_name IN VARCHAR2,
  in_tbl_name IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  full_id VARCHAR2(32);
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'select MAX('||DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(in_col_name)||') '
                  || 'FROM ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(in_tbl_name)
                  INTO full_id;
  return regexp_replace(full_id , '\d+', '')
         || TO_CHAR(regexp_replace(full_id , '\D+', '') + 1);
END;
/
```

For the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE brands (brand_id) AS
SELECT 'BRAND5' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
select get_id5('BRAND_ID' , 'BRANDS') AS id from dual;
```

Outputs:

> | ID |
> | --- |
> | BRAND6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a8a273fe955250745c84184af6d059bb)*

---

### A better solution

To generate the number, use a `SEQUENCE` or, from Oracle 12, an `IDENTITY` column and, if you must have a string prefix then use a virtual column to generate it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE brands(
  ID NUMBER
     GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
     PRIMARY KEY,
  brand_id VARCHAR2(10)
           GENERATED ALWAYS
             AS (CAST('BRAND' || TO_CHAR(id, 'FM000') AS VARCHAR2(10)))
);

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO brands (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
  INSERT INTO brands (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
  INSERT INTO brands (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);
END;
/

SELECT * FROM brands;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | BRAND_ID |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | BRAND001 |
> | 2 | BRAND002 |
> | 3 | BRAND003 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a9ee401cc8f155b68c7d4d1146b14ea8)*

Comment: Thanks , this has resolved my error. Now i am getting another error 'ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ' but all types seem ok to me.

Comment: @PalashJhamb That is because you are trying to concatenate strings with `+` (rather than `||`) and Oracle is trying to convert your `string_part` to a number and it raises that exception.

Comment: thanks  a lot , I was working on this since 3 hours :)